# Circular permutation - Arranging 4 persons around a circular table where 8 seats are there. (cond.)

Tags: permutations

> Suppose 4 persons A,B,C and D sit around a round table with 8 seats.
>   Rotation by 8,16,24,... seats defines same arrangement and other
>   rotations gives different arrangements.

If seats are identical, there are 7*6*5 arrangements as clarified [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694240/circular-permutation-arranging-4-persons-around-a-circular-table-where-8-seats/1694252?noredirect=1#1694240). After sturdying such questions,the following doubt came to my mind.

> Suppose persons and seats are identical. If so, what is
>   the required number of ways that these four people can be seated at the round table.?

How to approach such problem?

I guess this may not be simple as my previous question cited. I think, if persons and sets are identical, different arrangements may get identified only based on the empty seats between persons. How to approach this problem?

Comment: How can *persons* be identical ?

Comment: @true blue just took it as en example. Suppose 4 identical objects in place of 4 persons if that is an issue

Comment: Ok, consider it as 4 identical objects in 8 identical places around a circle

Comment: Yes, it then becomes a great deal more complicated ! Look up necklaces with beads of two colors (one for filled seats, and one for empty seats). To start you off, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015418/number-of-necklaces-of-beads-in-two-colors

Comment: According to the link that you provided, $7\cdot6\cdot5$ is **NOT** the answer (OP thought it was the answer but got a different one).

Comment: @barakmanos , for that question referred in that link, 7.6.5 is the answer (if seats are not labeled) and 8.7.6.5 is the answer (if seats are labeled), right? which is what I meant. please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to the problem of counting the different necklaces with 4 whites beads and 4 black beads. It's possible to solve that using a group acting on a set. The set is all the possibilities of coloring a fixed necklace with 4 black and 4 white beads. The group is the group of the rotations of an octagon ($\{k\frac{\pi}{4} \pmod{2\pi} \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, $+$).
Then, by counting the size of each orbit, it's possible to deduce the number of fundamentally different colorations of the necklace.
If you have already heard of groups and groups acting on sets, I can tell you more about this method.